# Why are new lines under commented lines automatically commented too?

Tags: visual-mode, comments

I will frequently use visual mode and the "norm" command to quickly comment out several lines.

Let's say this is my text (line numbers added for clarity):

```
1.  #include <iostream>
2.  using namespace std;
3.   
4.  int main()
5.  {
6.     cout << "Hello world!\n";
7.     return 0;
8.  }
```

And my cursor is on line 6. I hit 'v', 'j', and then

```
:'<,'>norm 0i//
```

now my text is:

```
1.  #include <iostream>
2.  using namespace std;
3.   
4.  int main()
5.  {
6.  //   cout << "Hello world!\n";
7.  //   return 0;
8.  }
```

and my cursor is on the second '/' on line 7.

But now, every new line I open starts with '//'. For example, if I hit 'o', and then enter twice, it will look like this:

```
1.  #include <iostream>
2.  using namespace std;
3.   
4.  int main()
5.  {
6.  //   cout << "Hello world!\n";
7.  //   return 0;
8.  //
9.  //
10. //
11. }
```

It will also do this with `'A<cr>'` and `'O'`.

What causes this? Is this a bug? Is there a way to get around it? It's not *super* annoying, but it does throw me off a little bit. That and I'm really curious at what causes this.

If it matters at all, I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and vim 7.4.488.

Comment: +1 for a nicer way to comment blocks than ma + motion + :'a,.s/^/\/\// :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing todo with the `normal` command or the visual block. This is due to a setting `'formatoptions'`, see [`:help 'formatoptions'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27). In particular, the mentioned behaviour comes from the flags `r` and `o`. If you don't like the behaviour, you can turn it off with `:set fo-=ro`.

See [`:help fo-table`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table) for the available flags.

Comment: Note that `:set fo-=ro` won't work if you use `:set fo=or` (different order), you need to use `:set fo-=r fo-=o`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your block includes the start of the next line (because you pressed `j`).

If you use `V` (upper case) to start your block, then you'll just have the line you want without pressing `j`.